# How to change the label of a button by using an if statement in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, if-statement, button, swiftui

I want my button to look different after pressing the button. I am trying to do so by using a ZStack and an if statement. I don't understand why it won't toggle between a black button and a white button...  P.S. I am getting experience using ObservableObject protocol.

```
class WelcomeButton: ObservableObject {
    @Published var hasBeenPressed = false
}

struct WelcomeScreenButton: View {
    @ObservedObject var welcomeButton = WelcomeButton()
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            if welcomeButton.hasBeenPressed {
                Circle()
                    .fill(Color(.white))
            }
            else {
                Circle()
                    .fill(Color(.black))
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var welcomeButton = WelcomeButton()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button(action: {welcomeButton.hasBeenPressed.toggle()})
            {
                WelcomeScreenButton()
            }
            .frame(width: 375, height: 375, alignment: .center)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're very close, but you have to have the same instance of the WelcomeButton ObservableObject shared between the two. Right now, they're two separate instances, so when you update `hasBeenPressed` on one, the other one doesn't know to change its state.

```
struct WelcomeScreenButton: View {
    @ObservedObject var welcomeButton : WelcomeButton //<-- here
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            if welcomeButton.hasBeenPressed {
                Circle()
                    .fill(Color(.white))
            }
            else {
                Circle()
                    .fill(Color(.black))
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var welcomeButton = WelcomeButton()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button(action: {welcomeButton.hasBeenPressed.toggle()})
            {
                WelcomeScreenButton(welcomeButton: welcomeButton) //<-- here
            }
            .frame(width: 375, height: 375, alignment: .center)
        }
    }
}
```

PS -- just as a general practice, it might be good to make the naming a little different just to keep things straight. `WelcomeButton` sounds like it's going to be a button. Naming it `WelcomeButtonViewModel` instead would make its intention more clear, although it wouldn't change the functionality at all.

Comment: Thank you! I've been trying to figure it out for way too long. This gets me moving forward with my learning :)